# SQL to compare two distinct group column different values in one table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Suppose one table t as following:

```
    c1 c2
    == ==
    a  1
    a  2
    b  1
    b  2
    b  3
    c  4
    c  2
```

We group this table by c1, and it has three groups: a, b, c.
I need to calculate the similarity of column c2 between two groups, like the following:

```
    sim(a,b) = 2(common value of c2 are 1 and 2)/3(all value)=2/3
    sim(b,c) = 1(b and c has only one value 2 in common)/4 = 1/4
    sim(a,c) = 1/3
```

Can we use SQL (Oracle 11g syntax first) to construct the expression above?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this query does what you want:

```
select t1.c1, t2.c1, count(*) as NumInCommon,
       (select count(distinct t.c2)
        from t
        where t.c1 in (t1.c1, t2.c1)
       ) as NumInTotal
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.c2 = t2.c2
group by t1.c1, t2.c1
```

Comment: This sql run in oracle will show, group by syntax wrong!